# splitting the words in a row to several row based on certain value of another column Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe **df**:

```
columnId     column2                                                                  column3    countsOfWord
id1          hogedijk klarenbeek                                                       2016        2
id2          hogedijk klarenbeek zuidoost hogedijk klarenbeek zuidoost                 2012        6
id3          zuidoost clouds                                                           2010        2
id4          artzuid zuidoost hogedijk klarenbeek zuidoost clouds hogedijk klarenbeek  2019        8
```

I desperately need to split the rows where the **countsOfWords** above **2 times** such as **id2** and **id4** to equal parts so that the column of **countsOfWords** of those rows only contain two words each without altering the **columnId** and **column3**. My **df** dataframe would look like this:

```
columnId     column2                                                                  column3    countsOfWord
id1          hogedijk klarenbeek                                                       2016        2
id2          hogedijk klarenbeek                                                       2012        2
id2          zuidoost hogedijk                                                         2012        2
id2          klarenbeek zuidoost                                                       2012        2
id3          zuidoost clouds                                                           2010        2
id4          artzuid zuidoost                                                          2019        2
id4          hogedijk klarenbeek                                                       2019        2
id4          zuidoost clouds                                                           2019        2
id4          hogedijk klarenbeek                                                       2019        2
```

anyone can help me?

I tried this code, but it is not automatically for **countsOfWords** above **2 times**:

```
df['column2'].iloc[1][0:len(df['column2'].iloc[0])//2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC we do `explode` then `cumcount` split the group to sub group

```
s=df.assign(column2=df.column2.str.split(' ')).explode('column2')

s=s.groupby([s.columnId,s.groupby('columnId').cumcount()//2]).\
        agg({'columnId':'first','column2':' '.join,'column3':'first','countsOfWord':'first'})
s=s.assign(countsOfWord=2).reset_index(drop=True)
s
  columnId              column2  column3  countsOfWord
0      id1  hogedijk klarenbeek     2016             2
1      id2  hogedijk klarenbeek     2012             2
2      id2    zuidoost hogedijk     2012             2
3      id2  klarenbeek zuidoost     2012             2
4      id3      zuidoost clouds     2010             2
5      id4     artzuid zuidoost     2019             2
6      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
7      id4      zuidoost clouds     2019             2
8      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
```

Or `findall` + `explode`

```
df.assign(column2=df.column2.str.replace(' ','-').str.findall("-".join(["[^-]+"] * 2))).explode('column2')
  columnId              column2  column3  countsOfWord
0      id1  hogedijk-klarenbeek     2016             2
1      id2  hogedijk-klarenbeek     2012             6
1      id2    zuidoost-hogedijk     2012             6
1      id2  klarenbeek-zuidoost     2012             6
2      id3      zuidoost-clouds     2010             2
3      id4     artzuid-zuidoost     2019             8
3      id4  hogedijk-klarenbeek     2019             8
3      id4      zuidoost-clouds     2019             8
3      id4  hogedijk-klarenbeek     2019             8
```

Comment: I don't understand why the first code line doesn't work. I tried it like this:

`s=df.assign(['column2']=df['column2''].str.split(' ')).explode('column2'')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (using `str.split()` with `zip()` and then [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) ):

```
df = df.assign(
        column2=df['column2'].apply(lambda x: [i + ' ' + j for i, j in zip(x.split()[::2],x.split()[1::2])])
    ).explode('column2')
df['countsOfWord'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  columnId              column2  column3  countsOfWord
0      id1  hogedijk klarenbeek     2016             2
1      id2  hogedijk klarenbeek     2012             2
1      id2    zuidoost hogedijk     2012             2
1      id2  klarenbeek zuidoost     2012             2
2      id3      zuidoost clouds     2010             2
3      id4     artzuid zuidoost     2019             2
3      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
3      id4      zuidoost clouds     2019             2
3      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
```

Comment: why does it say _dataframe object has no attribute explode_?

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani What version of `pandas` are you using? `explode()` was introduced in version `0.25.0`

Answer (score 1):

We can split your values to a list, then split them in equal chunks of 2 elements.

Then we check where the number of elements `> 2` and `explode` those rows:

```
splitted = df['column2'].str.split()
lists = splitted.apply(lambda lst: [lst[i::len(lst)//2] for i in range(len(lst)//2)])
df['column2'] = np.where(splitted.str.len().gt(2), lists, df['column2'])

dfn = df.explode('column2')

dfn['column2'] = np.where(
    dfn['column2'].apply(type).eq(list), 
    dfn['column2'].str.join(', '), 
    dfn['column2']
)

dfn['countsOfWord'] = dfn['column2'].str.split().str.len()
```

```
  columnId                 column2  column3  countsOfWord
0      id1     hogedijk klarenbeek     2016             2
1      id2      hogedijk, hogedijk     2012             2
1      id2  klarenbeek, klarenbeek     2012             2
1      id2      zuidoost, zuidoost     2012             2
2      id3         zuidoost clouds     2010             2
3      id4       artzuid, zuidoost     2019             2
3      id4        zuidoost, clouds     2019             2
3      id4      hogedijk, hogedijk     2019             2
3      id4  klarenbeek, klarenbeek     2019             2
```

Comment: i tried this but apparently there is a data loss after I applied this code @Erfan

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```py
df["column2"]=df["column2"].str.split(r"(?:([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+))\s+")

df=df.explode("column2").query("column2!=''")

#in case if it's given uou always have even number of words:
df["countOfWords"]=2
#otherwise:
df["countOfWords"]=df["column2"].str.count(r"\s").add(1)
```

Output:

```py
  columnId              column2  column3  countOfWords
0      id1  hogedijk klarenbeek     2016             2
1      id2  hogedijk klarenbeek     2012             2
1      id2    zuidoost hogedijk     2012             2
1      id2  klarenbeek zuidoost     2012             2
2      id3  hogedijk klarenbeek     2010             2
3      id4     artzuid zuidoost     2019             2
3      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
3      id4      zuidoost clouds     2019             2
3      id4  hogedijk klarenbeek     2019             2
```

**Now to break it down**:

The only tricky part in here is the regex:
`(?:([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+))\s+`

`\s` stands for single white space

`\s+` stands for one or more white spaces (just to be safe)

`[^\s]+` stands for one, or more characters that are **not** white spaces

`(?:...)` will use the pattern after colon as preceding part for the delimiter

So in essence you split by: one or more white spaces, that are preceded by (the whole thing together) one or more non white space character, followed by one or more white space, followed by one or more non white space character.